# I have a problem with pulse audio on Ubuntu mate 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, mate

When I fire up my machine (Dell insprion n5110) most of the times the audio does not work ! I keep restarting my machine until it works.
I can't access the sound preferences as I get "Waiting for sound system to respond" dialog. 
And when I try to run VLC from  terminal I get:

```
pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
```

The message when I try to open sound preferences:

[image]

Comment: Does you guest account have audio?

Comment: No, It doesn't have audio when I encounter this issue.